# ListView Binding array of objects access variables

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, object, binding

**EDIT**
Turns out the problem was with getting the enclosure it was throwing an error casting MtObject to Enclosure that wasn't being detected by the debugger.
Marked Andy's solution as correct as it is, and it helped me to see the problem was not in the ListView code, thank you andy

So i have been searching around and don't seem to be able to find the right answer.
Basically i have a ListView which i have bound to an array of Animals and one animal has a property of another object Enclosure, and im trying to bind the enclosure name like this

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Enclosure"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Enclosure.Name}" />
```

this is clearly wrong but i think shows what I'm trying to achieve,
The basic layout is object.object.

The full ListView below

```
<ListView Margin="20,0,20,0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="displayResults" SelectionChanged="displayResults_SelectionChanged_1">
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="45" />
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView x:Name="gridView">
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Photo" CellTemplate="{StaticResource PhotoTemplate}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GivenName}" />
                                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Enclosure.Id}" Header="Enclosure"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Species"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SpeciesName}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="DOB"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Dob}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Average Life Span"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AverageLifeSpan}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Natural Habitat"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NaturalHabitat}" />

                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
```

How the enclosure  get/set

```
public Enclosure Enclosure {
        get {
            return ((Enclosure)(GetSuccessor(GetEnclosureRelationship(Database))));
        }
        set {
            SetSuccessor(GetEnclosureRelationship(Database), value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, I think it's what you're after?

**Results**

[image]

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Enclosure" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Enclosure.Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Taste good?" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TastesGood}">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Checked="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Animal : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Enclosure enclosure;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(Animal), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public bool TastesGood
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(TastesGoodProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TastesGoodProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TastesGoodProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TastesGood", typeof(bool), typeof(Animal), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public Enclosure Enclosure
        {
            get { return enclosure; }
            set
            {
                enclosure = value;
                PropertyChangedEventHandler temp = PropertyChanged;
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Enclosure"));
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    public class Enclosure : DependencyObject
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(Enclosure), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public string Location
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LocationProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LocationProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LocationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Location", typeof(string), typeof(Enclosure), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Animal> Animals
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<Animal>)GetValue(AnimalsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AnimalsProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AnimalsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Animals", typeof(ObservableCollection<Animal>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Animals = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();
            Animals.Add(new Animal() { Name = "Cow", TastesGood = true, Enclosure = null });
            Animals.Add(new Animal()
            {
                Name = "Chicken",
                TastesGood = true,
                Enclosure =
                    new Enclosure()
                    {
                        Name = "chicken coop",
                        Location = "outside"
                    }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this seem to work in this situation, however my Animal class inherits MtObject because im connecting to the Matisse object database, is it possible to do this without the need for DependencyObject?

Comment: If you need updates to the properties after initialization then you'll need to Implement INotifyPropertyChanged, will update

Comment: in the update I've removed the dependency property for Enclosure and instead had it call the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event.

Comment: Lets say for now that i dont need to update the properties, what is the simplest way i can simple display the data without the need for DependencyObject, so if we just have simple class definitions is there a way to access the bound data

Comment: I think the only requirement to using {Binding Enclosure.Name} is that it's a property.

Comment: I have tried all the properties from Enclosure, i cant even get it to display the objects toString by just using {Binding Enclosure}